# Error: The Angular AoT build failed. See the issues above

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, ionic-native

I try to deploy my app to APK with
https://ionicframework.com/docs/intro/deploying/
but I have issues in CLI 'ionic cordova build android --prod --release'

> Error: The Angular AoT build failed. See the issues above

[image]

How can I solve this please

Comment: Error seems obvious. There is a problem with ionic-select-searchable plugin

Comment: @StephanStrate please make your comment an answer. Then, OP, please accept it. Just to change the status of this post.

Answer (score 1):

The plugin ionic-select-searchable can not find one specific template. You should consider opening an issue at their GitHub page.